# XML xs:choice SQLXMLBulkload

Tags: sqlxml

I have some XML files that I need to batch process into SQL Server. The following Schema and XML sections outline an area I'm having trouble with.

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="TextLine" type="xs:string" sql:field="AdvertLine" sql:relation="XmlAdvert" sql:relationship="XmlAdvert" />
            <xs:element name="BreakPoint" sql:is-constant="1" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<Advert>
 <AdvertText>
  <TextLine>Isuzu 4 X 4TRUCKMAN</TextLine> 
  <BreakPoint /> 
  <TextLine>2.0TD, Red, 5 dr, 60,000 miles, MOT, 5 SEATER</TextLine> 
  <BreakPoint /> 
  <TextLine>£2500</TextLine>
  <BreakPoint /> 
  <TextLine>01234 567890</TextLine> 
 </AdvertText>
</Advert>
```

But since xs:choice isn't supported in SQLXMLBulkload I wondered if there was another way of representing this as without the xs:choice section the xs:sequence is invalid as soon as it hits the second TextLine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SQLXMLBulkload, but here are my thoughts:

I'm not sure if there's any relationship between adjacent `TextLine` and `BreakPoint` elements. Assuming that there isn't, then the simplest solution may be to use XSLT to transform the schema and data to eliminate the need for the `choice`.

Note that I've inserted `maxOccurs="unbounded"` on both elements. If that doesn't work, there's an alternate approach that should work; see below.

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="TextLine" type="xs:string" sql:field="AdvertLine" sql:relation="XmlAdvert" sql:relationship="XmlAdvert" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="BreakPoint" sql:is-constant="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The equivalent XML would be:

```
<Advert>
 <AdvertText>
  <TextLine>Isuzu 4 X 4TRUCKMAN</TextLine> 
  <TextLine>2.0TD, Red, 5 dr, 60,000 miles, MOT, 5 SEATER</TextLine> 
  <TextLine>£2500</TextLine>
  <TextLine>01234 567890</TextLine> 
  <BreakPoint /> 
  <BreakPoint /> 
  <BreakPoint /> 
 </AdvertText>
</Advert>
```

But for all I know, SQLXMLBulkload won't like that arrangement either. In that case, based only on your example XML, I would bet that it would accept this:

with the matching XML being:

```
<Advert>
 <AdvertText>
    <TextLines>
      <TextLine>Isuzu 4 X 4TRUCKMAN</TextLine> 
      <TextLine>2.0TD, Red, 5 dr, 60,000 miles, MOT, 5 SEATER</TextLine> 
      <TextLine>£2500</TextLine>
      <TextLine>01234 567890</TextLine>
    </TextLines> 
  <BreakPoints> 
      <BreakPoint /> 
      <BreakPoint /> 
      <BreakPoint /> 
  </BreakPoints> 
 </AdvertText>
</Advert>
```

That still leaves open the question of how to write the XSLT that you'd need, but perhaps it's a start.

Comment: I think you might be right. I don't like the structure of the XML but there isn't much I can do about that other than a bit of pre-processing before I send it into SQLXMLBulkload. All i need to do is strip out the empty BreakPoint elements and it all works beautifully.